# Backbone: Validations being run only on set() parameters

Tags: javascript, validation, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have an issue where if I run a model.set({field: 'value'}), that model's validations will run as if the explicitly specified field is the only parameter set for the model.

What I mean is, if I have a validation that demands the presence of fields 'first_field' and 'second_field', running model.set({third_field: 'value'}) will fail validation, even if first_field and second_field have already been set. From console, first_field and second_field are available both before and after the validation is run...but console.log has the (attrs) field as populated by only the third field inside the validate function.

From what I've read in the official documentation my pattern for the validation method is fine...but something is clearly wrong. Any ideas appreciated, code below:

```
class MyModel extends Backbone.Model
  # ...
  validate: (attrs) ->
    errors = []
    valid = true
    console.log attrs
    if (!attrs.first_field)
      errors.push('You must add a first field')
    if (errors.length > 0)
      return errors
  # ...
```

And from console, if I run

```
m = window.router.my_models.test_model  # Contains attributes 'first_field' and 'second_field'
m.set({new_field: 'test value'})
```

It will return a 'false', which is coming from the validation. A console.log on attrs inside the validate method confirms the only attrs value present is the explicity-set 'new_field'

Comment: Is this for a non-current version of Backbone? Based on my debugging, it looks like the whole model's attributes are being sent to validate() because of this line in Backbone.Model._validate(): "attrs = _.extend({}, this.attributes, attrs);"

Comment: Yes - backbone has changed significantly since this was written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [backbone docs](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-validate):

> [The validate method] is passed the attributes that are about to be
>   updated

so the `attrs` object correctly only contains `new_field`. If you want to access other fields of the model you could probably do `this.get("first_field");`

Answer (score 2):

Only the attributes that are being changed are passed to the `validate` method, which in your example is `new_field`

It's an easy fix to update your validate method to see if `first_field` is present.

Instead of

```
if (!attrs.first_field)
  errors.push('You must add a first field')
```

replace it with

```
if (!this.get('first_field'))
  errors.push('You must add a first field')
```